# Print data from database by user keywords using php and sql

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I've been searching for a way to be able to make the user enter keywords (through HTML forms), and use this information to print the right data from the database back to the user (using php and sql).

Until now, I managed only to print data from the database using a "permanent" SQL query, heres what I mean:

```
<html>

<body>
<?php
// Connecting to the database
$con = @mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
if (!$con) die("Could not connect to the server!");
if (!@mysql_select_db('user')) die('Couldn\'t locate the database!');

$result=@mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Customer');  //BY THIS LINE I MEAN PERMANENT
if(! $result)
{
die('<p>Error</p>');
}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo('<p>'.$row['firstName']."&nbsp".$row['lastName'].'</p>');
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

It simply prints all the first name and last name in the customer table.
how can I change this code in order to be able to get for example customer name from the user, and then run a SQL query with the name the user gave me, and then print the results back on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

A. remove all the @. You want to catch errors, not surpress them.

B. You'll need to get the user submitted variable from $_POST, escape it, then add it as a WHERE clause.

C. Look into mysqli/PDO.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really new to this, I didn't understand what you mean.
Is there an actual code/example for this?

Comment: `$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE \`field\` = '$search'";`

etc.